# Error 001359 when publishing map service to ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I encountered this error when trying to publish a map service to an ArcGIS Server 10.1 (installed on linux). [image]

> --------------------------- Service Publishing Result
>   --------------------------- Packaging succeeded, but publishing failed.
>
> ERROR 001359: Failed to connect to the server.
>
> Please consult the GP Results Window for enhanced error description

.

Other info:
The geodatabase is registered with the server. And it did work in the past.
We use a PostgreSQL gdb server.

Comment: Is there any more information in the Results window in ArcMap?

Comment: In Results , the message is the same "Failed to connect to the server'

Comment: OK. Do you have PublishingTools service running (under System folder in the Server connection)? I am not an expert on Linux, but could any security settings change their thus empeding ArcGIS connect to the Server? I am also interested to see what happens if you stage an .sd file (with the option to embed data), and then use ArcGIS Server Manager web application to publish .sd file as a service. Would it work?

Answer (score 3):

apparently in our case it was an IP problem. we changed the IP of our gis server a couple of days ago. and the gdb didn't recognized the new ip, so changed back to the old IP.

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me out of the blue and I checked a few things including those listed above.  Nothing helped.  Turns out it was failing because I had Characters on the layer names that it didn't like for example '+', '<' but commas work fine.

Comment: I recently had the same issue. I came across this...http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00sq00000095000000

Answer (score -1):

So navigate to your server manager > services > Site root > publishing tools > edit service security > check (public,Available to everyone) > save.